# Find width and height of image after scaling

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am using cocos2d to develop a game and I came across below situation..Please some one guide me

```
this.scalesizex = this.image.height/winSize.height*0.7;
this.scalesizey = this.image.width/winSize.width*0.7; 

myNode.scaleX = this.scalesizex;
myNode.scaleY = this.scalesizey;
```

In Above code I am trying to scale my image to 1/7 of my screen size , I know the original image width and height , Can any one tell me is it possible to get the image width and height after scaling ?

p.s: I am unable to set actual image height and width  , So I am using scale to reduce my image width and height to fit my screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale the image to 1/7th of your screen size, the scale should be computed as follows:

```
this.scaleX = winSize.width / (this.image.width * 7);
this.scaleY = winSize.height / (this.image.height * 7);
```

Then, you can compute the new width and height by multiplying the image's original width and height with these scales.